# How to disable codelens in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've searched but didn't find any info on how to disable references (or the codelens completely) in the Visual Studio Code, they're quite useless and annoying for me.

Comment: @Louy Google is your friend, but a short description might be that it adds annotations inline with your code, to show you certain details that you might not otherwise see, such as counts of references to properties and fields.

Comment: [This feature request on the VSCode repo concerns improving the CodeLens UI so that you don't have to turn it off](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23652).

Comment: I created an extension called [Setting Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.setting-toggle) which lets me turn the codeLens on and off easily. My extension also lets you toggle any vs code setting. I found the jumping code when loading C# files very annoying, however the reference count is really helpful sometimes.

Comment: 2019 and still codelens is annoying. It would be nice if it was only shown at focus but until then, it looks much better without it.

Comment: 2021 and still codelens is annoying.

Comment: @Elkvis It's 2022 and not only is codelens still annyoing but this page is the top result on Google for "visual studio code disable codelens"

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Update: in the new settings editor of VSCode, it's as simple as typing codelens in the search and ticking the first checkbox in the results:

[image]

---

For me, the setting that fixed it was:

`"editor.codeLens": false`

in my user preferences json file.

Comment: Ctrl + , (comma) to quickly open Settings and start searching.  For reference for anyone like me who doesn't have it memorized. :)

Answer (score 231):

You can enable or disable code lense by setting `editor.codeLens` to `true` or `false` in user settings (see https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_reference-information for more info).

Comment: Latest vscode has a search function in the settings, just type in codelens and uncheck the box.

Comment: Where is settings?

Comment: I just right clicked on one of the references in a class and they all went away.

Comment: @Sam Are you saying that you couldn't find menu item `File`  - `Preferences` - `Settings`?

Comment: To sum to the answer, one could press ctrl +shift + p, search for user settings (json) and edit the line there, if the line do not exists, then just add the line and set it to false: "editor.codeLens": false

Answer (score 35):

To specifically disable the references in the C# editor, add this to your User Settings:

`"csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled": false`

This specifically hides the number of references in the C# editor while keeping the rest of CodeLens' features intact.

[MotKohn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356510/how-to-disable-codelens-in-vs-code/51863612#comment92603700_51863612) also pointed out that you can use `javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled` or `typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled` below. Make sure you give them some points if that helped!

Comment: 2023 update: this setting has been changed to `dotnet.codeLens.enableReferencesCodeLens`

Answer (score 34):

Step by step:

1- Press **CTRL+SHIFT+P** and search for "User Settings", and open settings.json file. 
This file sits under:

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
```

[image: CTRL+SHIFT+P]

2- On right panel override setting "**editor.codeLens**" with "false" value.

[image: editor.codeLens]

Answer (score 19):

I disabled it by going to `file | preferences | settings`

[image: file preferences settings]

**Finally:**

```
Workspace | Text Editor | (scroll down a little)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For people using any **Linux OS**:

1. Go to `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings`
2. Under drop-down `Text Editor`, search for `Code Lens` and disable
   it.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using a single click on VS Code. Just install the extension `Setting Toggle` made by Ho-Wan on VS Code. 
Once you install, click on **T** as shown in the image to toggle Codelens.

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit awkward, but works very well! Upvoting! By default it is setup to toggle Code Lens, so no configuration needed. Bonus: you can now toggle lens from Chift+Ctrl+P by typing `Setting toggle`.

Comment: This is a great piece of additional information! It doesn't exactly qualify as an answer to the question where it is only asked to permanently disable Code Lens. But for those who want to disable/enable Code Lens on the fly, this is great! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut to toggle this feature on/off quickly: `CTRL+SHIFT+P` `Toggle TypeLens`

Comment: Please indicate why you are downvoting this answer. It is a valid answer to the question asked.  I offered it up as an alternative to workspace/user settings for those interested.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a VS Code native feature. Perhaps you are disabling it for the [TypeLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.typelens). You need to mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `editor.codeLens` property doesn't seem to work for F#, at least for the inline type-annotation lens. I needed to set:

`"FSharp.inlayHints.typeAnnotations": false`

to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options... > Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens. Update the checkboxes as you please.