# go to definition in vscode preview window ruins the edito

Tags: visual-studio-code

This annoying window when you go to definition is impossible to disable and has been a blemish on an otherwise first rate code editor.

For some reason it picks up .d.ts files and I get the window even when there is only one definiton.  I would love to remove this feature but it does not seem possible.

Below is a screen shot of it picking up a definition and for some reason a react  index.d.ts file.  So annoying, I can never go to the definition, I've got to click about until the preview window decides it wants to close:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable codelens in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356510/how-to-disable-codelens-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally cured it for me was:

`"editor.gotoLocation.multiple": "goto"`