# How to get rid of "references" code annotation in vs code "C# dotnet 5" project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

This picture says it all... I created a dotnet 5 project using the standard command line for a console project:

```
dotnet new console -n microsoft.botsay -f net5.0
```

.... started visual studio code, installed the recommended add on that visual studio asked me to install for C#....

Now this picture explains my annoyance... How to get rid of all of the code annotations that say "references" and get more compact code without all the information I don't want about references?

[image: This picture says it all]

Comment: It's called codelens. Just find it in settings and disable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable codelens in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356510/how-to-disable-codelens-in-vs-code)