# How can I turn off the references on Vscode? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have this references in top of variables and voids. I tryed to serch it in options but I don't see an option to turn them off.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356510/how-to-disable-codelens-in-vs-code) this help

Answer (score 0):

File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Code Lens

[image]