# how to remove the vscode suggestions for haskell?

Tags: haskell, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

[image]

I do not want the white line suggestions like main :: IO()
and import Data.List(), in the start it did run well without showing the above suggestions, but randomly today it started showing up

I tried removed any AI suggestions extensions, but it is still showing up.
What to do ?

Comment: It's a fair question, though I'd say these suggestions are actually quite reasonable.

Comment: I would highly recommend giving `main` a type signature. I've seen several people make mistakes that could have been caught by the compiler, but they didn't give `main` a type signature. For example, if you instead have `return $ print $ spread "abcd"` in your code, it will compile but it will do nothing when you run it. There are more subtle examples of this, too. *However*, if you have `main :: IO ()` then you would get a type error! Like I said, I've seen people run into this several times and it can be very confusing (without `main :: IO ()`)

Answer (score 2):

VS Code calls these "code lenses".  You can globally disable them using the `editor.codeLens` setting, as explained in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356510/how-to-disable-codelens-in-vs-code).

If you want more fine-grained control, you can select "Extensions" in the left toolbar, click on the "Settings" gear icon for the "Haskell" extension, and select "Extension Settings".  There are several settings, and they aren't all consistently named, but searching for the word "lens" may help.  The two settings that appear relevant to the code lenses in your example are:

```
Haskell > Plugin > Import Lens: Code Lens On
Haskell > Plugin > Ghcide-type-lenses: Global On
```